# How to remove a child from a random array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, random, actionscript

I have an array that randomly creates 10 dots. However there's a certain area where I do not want them to be created. How can I achieve this? My code gives me error 2025.

*"The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller."*

It will occasionally output the totalDots as instructed, `(trace""+totalDots)`, but 90% of the time it will give me the error.

```
public var numDots:Array = [];
public var totalDots:int = numDots.length;
public var box:Box = new Box();

public function addBox():void
{
     box.x = stageWidth/2;
     box.y = stageHeight/2;
     addChild(box);
}
private function addDot():void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var dot:Dot = new Dot();
        dot.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * stageWidth);
        dot.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * stageHeight);
        this.addChild(dot);
        totalDots++;
        trace(""+totalDots);

        for(var j:int = 0; j < totalDots; j++)
        {
            if(numDots[j].hitTestObject(box))
            {
                stage.removeChild(numDots[j]);
                numDots.splice(j, 1);
                totalDots--;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this box just a regular rectangle?

Comment: For now, as a placeholder. It will change later on to a slightly more complex shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is your nested loop. With each iteration, you add one new dot, and then loop over all of the existing ones, and remove them if it collides with the box. I don't think that's what you intended to do.

It looks like you just want to make sure the dots are not added within a certain area. In that case, keep it simple with a do while loop:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var dot:Dot = new Dot();
    this.addChild(dot);
    do {
        dot.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * stageWidth);
        dot.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * stageHeight);
    } while(dot.hitTestObject(box))
    totalDots++;
    trace(""+totalDots);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the dots are still being created on the box. I should also note that the dots will be moving in random directions.

Comment: @null Did I miss something? The while loop should force the dot position to change any time it collides with the box.

Comment: @Matt I just tested my code, and it worked for me... Dots and box never collide.

Comment: @Karma duuuh, sorry I jumped to wrong conclusions too quickly. You are right.

Comment: @karma I moved the addDot() function from the main Document Class function to an ENTER_FRAME function and it works, although it keeps repeating, putting an infinite amount of dots on the screen. Can you please explain why it can't be in the main Document Class function?

Comment: @Matt my guess is something to do with how you are setting stageWidth/stageHeight. I noticed you are not using stage.stageWidth or stage.stageHeight... You should definately remove the function from the enterFrame tho, or it will add 10 new dots on every frame update.

Comment: @karma I am setting it with `public var stageWidth:int = 1600;` and the same way for `stageHeight`. Using `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight` returns the same results when `addDot()` is in the main function (they still collide with the box).

Comment: @Matt I'm not exactly sure how hitTestObject is calculated, but it's possible it uses local coordinates, rather then global. That would mean that the position of box might different in your Document Class then it is in your internal Class, which could cause the restriction on the dots to change. Can you trace the position of box from within each function?

Comment: @karma It outputted the windows center coordinates, as desired. The position of the box is dictated in the document class. There is nothing in the Dot class. I put `addDot` into an `ADDED_TO_STAGE` function and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You never add any dot to your array.

You add the dot to the display list like so:

```
this.addChild(dot);
```

and you try to remove it like so:

```
stage.removeChild(numDots[j]);
```

Despite the fact that the dot is never added to the array, this couldn't have worked even if it was. That's because `this` is not `stage`. They are two different things.

You should **never** use `stage.addChild()` (check the documentation for more info on that). Just call `addChild()` all the time which is equivalent to `this.addChild()`. This ensures that you always operate on one and the same `DisplayObjectContainer`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can avoid the trial loop altogether by calculating a random value with the proper interval (the difference between the include and exclude areas) and deriving `x` and `y` coordinates from that.

The following code (written in a language I do not know, apologies if the syntax is faulty) has two cases.  The `if` case handles the situation where the dot will appear left or right of the exclusion box, and the range of `x` values is restricted to being left or right of that box.  The `else` case is where the dot will appear above or below the box, and the `x` values are not restricted.

```
var interval:int = stageWidth * stageHeight - box.w * box.h;
var cut:int = interval - (stageWidth - box.w) * box.h;
for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var r:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * interval);
    var x:int;
    var y:int;
    if (r >= cut) {
        r -= cut;
        y = r / (stageWidth - box.w);
        x = r - y * (stageWidth - box.w);
        y += box.y;
        if (x >= box.x) x += box.w;
    } else {
        y = r / stageWidth;
        x = r - y * stageWidth;
        if (y >= box.y) y += box.h;
    }
    var dot:Dot = new Dot();
    dot.x = x;
    dot.y = y;
    this.addChild(dot);
    totalDots++;
    trace(""+totalDots);
}
```

This assumes that `box` is entirely within `stageWidth,stageHeight`.

Also notable is that it allows the dots to overlap; same as the original code.

For more complex shapes you can set `box` to the largest rectangle fully enclosed by that shape so as to avoid many but not all retry cases.  This can be helpful for large shapes and many dots.  Or there are variations which might manage a perfect fit to another shape (eg., an ellipse).